# Use parameterised query to add column of Numeric type with Scale of 2 in Access using OldDb

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to add some columns in an `access` database using `Oledb` Command. The type of the column are different, like Currency(`OleDbType.Currency`), float with two decimal place (`OleDbType.Numeric`), integer(`OleDbType.Integer`) etc. the below code is what I am using to accomplish my task... But each and every time it Shows error Message saying Some..".. Error in Field Definition.." or as I change code sometime it shows "Syntax Error in Column Definition .." etc.

```
var insertColumnCommand = @"ALTER TABLE ProductRecordsTable ADD COLUMN [Price]= @ProductPrice, [Shipped(NoS)]= @ProductShippedNumber, [Returned(NoS)]= @ProductReturnedNumber, [Sold(NoS)]= @ProductSoledNumber, [Tax Percentage]= @ProductTaxPercentage";
var con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\MyDatabase.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password= 12345;");
using(con)
{
   var cmd = new OleDbCommand(insertColumnCommand, con);
   if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
       con.Open();
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductPrice", OleDbType.Currency);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductShippedNumber", OleDbType.Integer);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductReturnedNumber", OleDbType.Integer);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductSoledNumber", OleDbType.Integer);
   var parameter = new OleDbParameter("@ProductTaxPercentage",OleDbType.Numeric);
       parameter.Precision = 6;
       parameter.Scale = 2;
       cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();
}
```

I would also like to add option like putting `NULL` value in already existing rows of the table in the newly added columns, and `0(Zero)` will be inserted as `default` value, for the rows that will be added later on.But the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` like is too stubborn to not run successfully.

Comment: You cannot use parameters in this context. Parameters are used only to retrieve data or update it.

Comment: then @Steve please give me the command to specify how can the scale value be set using the traditional non-parameterised OldDb commands

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks @halfer, really thanks a lot... I never thought of this.. and as the link shared by you has embraced me with, I was in true HURRY, I will try to 'refrain' using such phrases in my question... I hope considering me as a mere newbie (see my reputation :p) I shall be forgiven.. :) Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments above, you cannot use parameters when you execute Data Definition Language commands like ALTER TABLE (this is true in any database I known of) In your specific case you can use the DECIMAL datatype for the columns that requires scale and precision values and no = between the name of the column and the type.

```
@"ALTER TABLE ProductRecordsTable 
    ADD COLUMN [Price] DECIMAL (10,2), 
               [Shipped(NoS)] INT, 
               [Returned(NoS)]  INT, 
               [Sold(NoS)] INT, 
               [Tax Percentage]  DECIMAL (6,2)";
```

Then suppose you want to set the Price to be NOT NULL. First execute a query to set every row to a predefined value

```
"UPDATE ProductRecordsTable SET Price = 0"
```

And now set the NOT NULL value on the column

```
@"ALTER TABLE ProductRecordsTable ALTER COLUMN [Price] DECIMAL (10,2) NOT NULL"
```

If you want to set a default value (for new records on some column

```
@"ALTER TABLE ProductRecordsTable ALTER COLUMN [Sold (NoS)] INT DEFAULT 0"
```

Comment: Thanks @Steve, Let me Check your Answer, if it resolves my problem, I shall mark it as answer. Thank you..

Comment: One more thing I shall like to add that can you help regarding my extra functionalities as I have added in the part below the code portion in my Question..                       "I would also like to add option like putting NULL value in already existing rows of the table in the newly added columns, and 0(Zero) will be inserted as default value, for the rows that will be added later on"

Comment: You can execute a query that sets the default value for the rows already present in the datatable (after adding the columns above) If you need to set a NOT NULL on some column then reexecute the ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN with NOT NULL for the column (of course this needs the previous command that sets a value for the existing rows)

Comment: Thanks @Steve, Let me give it a try.. :)

Comment: For the default value there is _ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN XXXX INT DEFAULT 0_